# NSIS uninstaller test opened file

Tags: file, nsis, uninstallation

For my uninstaller, I would like test recursively if a file in `$INSTDIR` is opened, and if a file is opened I would like show a dialog and close the uninstaller otherwise I execute the unstaller code.

Comment: for opened files at the time of removal, does the `Delete /REBOOTOK` help? (deletion postponed until next reboot).

Comment: Do you mean open/locked by another application?

Comment: I would prefer to forbid the uninstallation if a file is opened, because the PC can't be reboot.

Comment: Yes I mean, if the file already opened, it won't be able to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed by reading if the process is running or not by using FindProcDLL plug-in :
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_whether_your_application_is_running

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a straight forward way, but you can do the following:

- Recursively list all files and folders in $INSTDIR (How: Use FindFirst, FindNext as explained [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=175873))
- Test each file if it is already open (Use File commands)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for the executable file which are not deletable if they are opened.
So I wonder if it wouldn't be more simple to read if the procesus is launched or not ?